# How can I make a "Just Type" Qucik Action plugin in webOS 3.0?

Tags: webos

How can I make a "Just Type" "Quick Action" in webOS 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `appinfo.json`

```
"universalSearch": {
  "search":{
    "displayName": WHAT_DISPLAYS_TO_USER_IN_JUST_TYPE,
    "url": YOUR_APP_ID,
    "launchParam": "search"
  }
}
```

and then you can check in the app for search in `enyo.windowParams`

enyo.windowParams.search